# Array item using its own parent object index as its value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

lets say we have :

```
    let array_of_objects = [
    {
      "color": "purple",
      "type": "minivan",
      "id": this.object.index // i know this is not valid code,but can this somehow get its own index within the array as value ?

    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "type": "station wagon",
      "id": this.object.index  //this should be 1
    }
]
```

Actual question in code comments..
what i'm trying to do is to fill a form's inputs using an object,and i want to be able to display the actual index of the object within the array in one of the inputs

Comment: Why not map over this array and add the `id` later? What use case requires having all the indices as individual properties in the array?

Comment: You don't have to store the index in the object, you will need the index anyway when referring to the object, use that index instead of the value in the object.

Comment: i see your logic,so basically every time i add something in the array,loop it through and add the property

Comment: If you are running the loop on an array of objects, you will have the iteration variable right. If not that, and you are making the array on your own you can add it while making the array right

Comment: @VaggelisNos _“every time I add something in the array”_ — If you’re adding a single object to the existing array, then the `id` will just be `array_of_objects.length`. I don’t see why you would loop through the array _again_. It’s still not clear how this ID will be used. It’s very unlikely that you actually need this ID.

Comment: Your approach seems questionable. Arrays offer functionality like `filter` and `sort`, how would your approach go about that? Given what you want, would `id` reflect the changes introduced by those methods?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using index as id I suggest create a complex id or you can use `uuid()` library for creating **unique user id** [uuid npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
array_of_objects = array_of_objects.map((item, index) => ({ id: uuidv4(), ...item}))

console.log(array_of_objects);
```

Comment: its not my purpose to create a user id in this particular example,but i will save your suggestion for one of my other projects where i need one ! thank you

Comment: @VaggelisNos UUID is not about user ids. It's general-purpose., UUID stands for **u**niversally **u**nique **id**entifier.

Comment: What is it about then.
I looked over the package and it seems it returns a random unique complex hash string,it is for security purposes,right ?

Comment: No, it's simply for making sure you cannot end up with duplicate ids, which guarantees a 1:1 relationship between id and data item. Were it a hash string, then its value would depend on some sort of input that is being hashed. UUIDs have nothing to do with this.

Comment: UUIDs are definitely the way to go, if you need it to identify the item in other places of your code. UUIDs also "survive" sorting and filtering in a meaningful way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: @connexo yes you are right about uuid! also uuid can also be used as keys instead of name/title/index when looping through a array

Answer (score 0):

```js
   let array_of_objects = [
    {
      "color": "purple",
      "type": "minivan"

    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "type": "station wagon"
    }
];

array_of_objects = array_of_objects.map((item, index) => ({ id: index, ...item}))

console.log(array_of_objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the array without the id and add it afterwards using a for loop.

```
  let array_of_objects = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "type": "minivan",
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "type": "station wagon",
  }
]
for (let i = 0; i < array_of_objects.length; i++) {
  array_of_objects[i].id = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(arrayVarible)` to get the indexes of array which outputs as an array as well.

```js
let array_of_objects = [
    {
      "color": "purple",
      "type": "minivan",
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "type": "station wagon",
    }
];

console.log(Object.keys(array_of_objects))
```

Answer (score -2):

Each time the the array changes or you fill the form run this code

```
  console.log(array_of_objects.length-1)
```